# Losing headers from Relay server

Tags: email, spamassassin, rbl

Trying to troubleshoot spam filtering. I have a relay setup to accept all my incomming emails and filter them before it hits the main server. I cant seem to get spamassassin to put the headers in for score inside of /etc/spamassassin/local.cf

```
add_header all Status score=_SCORE_
add_header all Report _REPORT_
```

Im trying to see if this is being run

```
urirhssub       SEM_URIRED  urired.spameatingmonkey.net. A 2
body            SEM_URIRED  eval:check_uridnsbl('SEM_URIRED')
describe        SEM_URIRED  Contains a URI listed by SEM-URIRED
tflags          SEM_URIRED  net
score           SEM_URIRED  1
```

Does anyone know how i can troubleshoot this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, i got it to work by changing the header name to:

```
add_header all Relay-Status score=_SCORE_
add_header all Relay-Report _REPORT_
```